# MDX language independent date comparison

Tags: date, mdx

In short: I have a date typed property that i need to compare with now(), but two different environments (language settings) where this comparison has to work.

I have a the following code:

```
with
    member [Measures].[Opening] as
        CDate([Store].[Store].Properties('Opening')) // works with the english date

    member [Measures].[Opening] as // works with the german date
        DateSerial(
            Right([Store].[Store].Properties('Opening'),4),
            Mid([Store].[Store].Properties('Opening'),4,2),
            Left([Store].[Store].Properties('Opening'),2)
        )

    member [Measures].[IsOpen] as
        CASE 
            WHEN [Measures].[Opening] < NOW()
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
        END
```

`[Store].[Store].Properties('Opening')` is a date.

But there are two servers with different language settings this has to run on. One returning e.g. 02.10.2009 and the other 10/2/2009 for [Opening].

I need to find a solution working for both environments. (But can't change the language settings)

I tried formatting with FORMAT_STRING or LANGUAGE, but had no success what so ever.

Comment: which of my snippets helped?

Comment: the third one helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible idea is this:

```
  VBA!cdate(
    format(
      VBA!cdate([Store].[Store].Properties('Opening')),
      "dd MMMM yyyy"
    )
  )
```

A lot of warehouses use integers as their date keys - then the date format of the server would be slightly irrelevent as you could use this sort of construction:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Date as int] as
       [Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.Properties('Key0', Typed)
MEMBER [Measures].[Date Year] as
       Fix([Measures].[Date as int] / 10000)
MEMBER [Measures].[Date Month] as
       Fix(([Measures].[Date as int] - [Measures].[Date Year] * 10000) / 100)
MEMBER [Measures].[Date Day] as
       [Measures].[Date as int] - [Measures].[Date Year] * 10000 - [Measures].[Date Month] * 100

MEMBER [Measures].[DateValue_attempt1] as
       // convert it to Date data type and use a format string on that:
       DateSerial([Measures].[Date Year], [Measures].[Date Month], [Measures].[Date Day]),
       format_string = 'dd.MM.yyyy'
MEMBER [Measures].[DateValue_attempt2] as
       //if above fails maybe just convert it to string & do further conversion in client
       [Measures].[Date Day] + "." +
          [Measures].[Date Month] + "." +
             [Measures].[Date Year]
```

But a bit of a workaround for you might be to detect what the third character is and then use `IIF` or `CASE`:

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Opening] AS
       IIF(
          Mid([Store].[Store].Properties('Opening'),3,1) = '.'
         ,DateSerial(
            Right([Store].[Store].Properties('Opening'),4),
            Mid([Store].[Store].Properties('Opening'),4,2),
            Left([Store].[Store].Properties('Opening'),2)
          )
         ,CDate([Store].[Store].Properties('Opening')) 
       )
```